# Tail file and read aloud in real time

Tags: centos, terminal, audio

On CentOS 8 Stream, I'm trying to rig up a way to `tail -f` a text file, and as text is written to file it gets read aloud from bash.

I can do this as a one-time thing using Python3's `gtts-cli` and sox's `play`, and while both support reading from stdin they don't seem to do so in real-time. Rather they appear to parse everything when they receive an EOF.

Does anyone know of a way to kluge things together that would let me do this?

Comment: Did you switch off I/O buffering?